# Find string inside single and double quotation marks using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How to find string between `""` and `''` using regex. Just I want to create a function using PHP `preg_match_all()` function that will match all the static strings in a file, so probably we are creating a string using `""` and `''` so I need to find all such strings from a file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? RegEx may not be the appropriate solution, since you'll have to deal with (escaped) quotes inside the strings... like `'From time to "time"'` or `"From time to \"time\""`

Comment: I don't agree with the down vote since this is a genuine question.  Even if regex is not the correct solution.  Based on the OPS question despite being ambiguous simple answer is:  `/(["']+?)(.*?)(\1?)/`  - however @ericbn has a valid point regarding nesting; though this can be solved with a negative/lookahead in regex.

Comment: Do you want to search all static strings in a PHP file? Or are your searching in another specific format ?

Comment: @Ash if you consider it a good question post an answer with your answer.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard apparently the OP does, it's not a badly formatted question, or off-topic to the site therefore doesn't deserve a downvote.  I may well propose my answer but it doesn't mean I'm in a position to post a quick-oneliner right now.

Comment: What's the expected result for that string: `"abc\"\\{$string}\n\x50"`?

Answer (score 4):

You should be aware that inside those quoted "entities" you may find escaped quotes. The best way to match those strings is using a regex like this:

```
(?s)'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT8xO6/1)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(?s)'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*'|\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"/"; 
$str = "\"string 'c' \" string \" \" and ' string \"ste\" \' '"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/dcDyzH)

Comment: Nice solution, which passes the any-number-of-consecutive-antislashes test.

Answer (score 1):

This will match `"` and `'` strings:

```
/((?<!\\)["']).+?(?<!\\)\1/m
```

You can see the explanation of the regular expression [on this page](https://regex101.com/r/eJ2sF5/1).

Comment: [This is the case](https://regex101.com/r/oN1mK9/1) when your regex will fail (note the *\\\* at the right-hand `"`). I myself has been using look-behinds until I came across a real solution.

Comment: @stribizhev Corrected the regex. The first quote needed a negative lookbehind, as well. I think it should work now.

Comment: Let's say it will work in case there are no escaped entities, otherwise it may yield unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do what you want to do, just beware that you can't really identify the semantic differences between the apostrophe in "you're" from 'you're string'.

```
preg_match_all(
    "|(['\"])([^\"]*)(\1)|g",
    'This \'is a\' small "demo of what" you\'re trying, to "do"!'
);
```

**Reference**

- [PHP preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: Thank you for that. However, I can't forsee that example existing inside of a PHP file, I may be missing something, but good point.